# VB.NET: Display a string in different color

Tags: .net, vb.net, string-formatting

My VB.NET application generates an HTML table with numeric data. I wanted to format the numbers with commas and put brackets around negative numbers. That i did by specifying the format string in the `ToString()` method. What i want to do is change the color of the negative numbers to red. Any idea how this can be done? My sample code:

```
...
rowHTML.Append("<td align=""left"">" + num.ToString("#,##0.##;(#,##0.##)") + "</td>")
...
```

EDIT:
At this moment, i have added a check after the formatting is done to see if the first character has an opening bracket and then added the `font` tag:

```
tempString = num.ToString("#,##0.##;(#,##0.##)")
If tempString(0) = "(" Then
  rowHTML.Append("<td align=""left""><font color=""red"">" + tempString + "</font></td>")
Else
  rowHTML.Append("<td align=""left"">" + tempString + "</td>")
End If
```

Does that look good as a fix?

Answer (score 0):

I only could find this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/01/13/color-print.aspx

Where and how are you exactly *printing* the text?

Comment: I am putting the generated HTML in an HTML file.

Comment: then you are looking for some html tags:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_font_color.asp

I would recommend create an CSS file instead, and provide your tags with IDs and Classes

Comment: Please check my fix above. I am looking for a solution that could possibly lie within `ToString()` or some other method that will make those checks disappear.

Comment: got another solution: use css!:
<html>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="color:red"> Some colorized text
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Some text
</td>
</tr>
</table>
(try on browser)
PS: if it is for the negatives numbers, why don't you put some `if num<0 then`somewhere?

Comment: I have done that already. Check the edit section in my question.

Comment: Ok, that look's good but remember that the <font> tag is "deprecated". The standard says you might use the CSS style :D